# How do I print this pattern in java?

Tags: java, loops

I'm not able to print this pattern:-

```
90
890
7890
67890
567890
4567890
34567890
234567890
1234567890
```

I,ve already tried this:

```
class loop1
{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
           {    
            for(int j=9;j<10;j++)
               {   System.out.print(j);
                   j--; 
               }
            System.out.println("");
           }
    }
}
```

but get an output of unlimited `9`, a never ending loop.

Comment: Explain the logic you used in your current attempt. Why do you think it should work.

Comment: look closely at your inner loop : `for(int j=9;j<10;j++)`.

Comment: I've tried to use this logic:                                       9       //--
89 //++//--//--
789 //++//++//--//--//--
6789 //++//++//++//--//--//--//--
56789 //++//++//++//++//--//--//--//--//--

Comment: Technically you could just don't use loops and system.out.print the  pattern.

Comment: Wait, this is what design-patterns means ? I had it wrong the whole time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(10 - j);
        }
        System.out.println(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this its very simple 
working example is [here](http://ideone.com/k3Hv3X)

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("0");

for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--) {

s.insert(0, i);

System.out.println(s);
```

Result

90

890

7890

67890

567890

4567890

34567890

234567890

1234567890

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop is looping the wrong way; for a working solution, it should be going from 9 down to 1. Then, your inner for loop would be looping up to 9:

```
for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
    for(int j = i; j < 10; j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println(0);
}
```

The 0 can't be part of the loop because it doesn't fit with the 1-9 pattern. However, you could print the last digit of each number and cut the 0 part of the println statement:

```
for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
    for(int j = i; j < 10; j++) {
        String number = j + "";
        System.out.print(number.substring(number.length() - 1));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Even this is an infinite loop

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm such an idiot. It never occurred to me that it's the outer loop that needs decrement and not the inner one. All this time I was doing just the opposite of what you told. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("0");
for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
    s.append(i);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++) {    
   for(int j=10-i;j<10;)
      System.out.print(j++);
   System.out.println("0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am late but i have to post this because of my love for loops

```
public class SeriesLoop {


    public static void main(String a[]){


    for(int i=9;i>=1;i--){
        for(int j=i;j<=10;j++){
            System.out.print(j%10);

        }
    System.out.println();
    }

    }

}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/NUWqv0)

Cheers